# Dynamically adding table rows with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table that I need to dynamically add/remove rows from. Each row has a hyperlink in the final column to remove the record. Since you can dynamically add rows after the page loads, occasionally this record won't be found in the database.

When the user clicks on the "Delete" link, an `ajax` function is called to remove the record from the database. As long as the function server-side function does not crash, the operation will send back as a success.

Once the `ajax` function's `success` function is called, I would like to remove the `tr` from the table.

I can do this with each row that exists in the table once the page loads. The `ajax` function sends the proper info back to the server, and the `tr` is removed from the table. However for each `tr` I add after the `delete` `ajax` function will not fire, and the `tr` is left on the page.

**View**

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Agent Ids</legend>
            <table id="agentTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>State Code</th>
                        <th>Company Code</th>
                        <th>Agent ID</th>
                        <th>Non-Res Biz NY</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.BankListAgentIds)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("AgentIdPartial", item)
                    }
                </tbody>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class ="addCode">Add Another</a>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
```

**Parial View**

```
@model CollectionItemTest.Models.BankListAgentId
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("BankListAgentIds"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TableId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BankID)
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StateCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NonResBizNY)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentId)
        </td> 
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "", "",  new { href = "javascript:void(0)", id = Model.TableId  })
        </td>                              
    </tr>    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#agentTable').on('click', 'tr a', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRow", "BankList")',
                data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                success: function () {
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                }
            });
        })
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.addCode').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BlankRow", "BankList")',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#agentTable > tbody").append(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller Functions**

```
    public JsonResult DeleteRow(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0) return null;

        var agent = (from a in db.BankListAgentIds
                     where a.TableId == id
                     select a).FirstOrDefault();

        if (agent == null) return Json("Agent Id not found", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        db.BankListAgentIds.Remove(agent);

        return null;
    }

    public ViewResult BlankRow()
    {
        return View("AgentIdPartial", new BankListAgentId());
    }
```

Comment: It seems something isn't getting bound properly, Just wondering, Why did you put the function inside a jquery object call? `$(function() { ... ` Did you try simply setting the listener inside the document ready function ?

Comment: In the case you're talking about, I generally put an onclick event right in the element I want to delete. So your delete link would be like `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteRow(this);">delete</a>`

Comment: @Patrick - yes I tried in the doc.ready function first but got the same results.

Comment: @nmarsh - that only sends the hyperlink to the `deleteRow` function. Any way to send the whole `tr`, or, in the `deleteRow` function, know which row I need to remove?

Comment: I still don't 100% understand why is your .on event inside a jquery object, Is there a reason for that?

Comment: That's just my latest attempt. This and the `document.ready` function do the same thing: they will call the ajax function and remove the row is the `tr` was there when the page loaded. If not then nothing happens. '

Comment: @NealR check out jQuery's `parent()`: http://api.jquery.com/parent/  you should be able to call `a.parent(tr)` to get the row you need

Comment: @nmarsh - just fyi I've tried the following with no luck: `$(row).closest('tr').remove();` `$(row).parent('tr').remove();` `$(row).parents('tr').remove();`.

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714530/attaching-click-methods-to-classes-loaded-via-ajax) post and used the `.live` command.

```
    $('#agentTable').live('click', 'tr a', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRow", "BankList")',
            data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function () {
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Live is actually deprecated, you should use .on, write the code correctly outside of a jquery object 